# why this code didn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem to resolve, I don't understand why my code doesn't work correctly.

> Write a JavaScript function that takes as input an array of two numbers (start and end) and prints at the console a HTML table of 3 columns.
>
> - Column 1 should hold a number `num`, changing from start to end.
> - Column 2 should hold `num*num`.
> - Columns 3 should hold "yes" if `num` is Fibonacci number or "no" otherwise.
>
> The table should have header cells titled "Num", "Square" and "Fib". See the below examples.

**Input**
The input data comes as array of two numbers: start and end. The input data will always be valid and in the format described. There is no need to check it explicitly.

**Output**
Print at the console the above described table in the same format like the examples below. Don't add additional spaces. Whitespace and character casing are important, so please use the same as in the below examples.

**Constraints**
•   The input is passed to the first JavaScript function found in your code as array of 2 elements.
•   The numbers start and end are positive integers in the range [1…1 000 000] and start ≤ end.
•   Allowed working time for your program: 0.2 seconds.
•   Allowed memory: 16 MB.

This code is not the same by the requirement of problem, but the idea is the same I guess.

Here is my code:

```js
var fib = [];
var a, b, result;
a = 0;
b = 1;
result = b;
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    result = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = result;

    fib.push(result);
}
console.log("<table>");
console.log("<tr><th>Num</th><th>Square</th><th>Fib</th></tr>");
var start = 2;
var end = 6;
    function isFib(start, end) {
        for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
            fib.forEach(function (element) {
                if (i === element) {
                    return "yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "no";
                }
            });
        }
    }
function buildTable() {
    for(var j = start; j < end; j++) {
        console.log("<tr><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + j * j + "</td><td>" + isFib(start, end) +  "</td></tr>");
    }
}
buildTable(start, end);
```

This code is not the same by the requirement of problem, but the idea is same i guess.

Comment: Why are you writing HTML to the console log?

Comment: What does _"This code is not the same by the requirement of problem, but the idea is the same I guess."_ mean? Did you write that code?

Comment: The HTML code is a string. Yes, I wrote this code and I don't understand where I wrong.

Comment: You are always launching `isFib` with parameters `start` and `end`. You should figure out whether `j` is a Fibonacci number, but you are not passing `j` to the `isFib` function. Also, the loop inside `isFib` always returns from the first iteration, either "yes" or "no". Please fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of feels like I am doing one of your homework assignments but here you go.

```js
var a = [1,25];

function fib(n){
  return n<2?n:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
function isFib(n){
  var tryNum = 0;
  do {
   var fibNum = fib(tryNum++);
  } while (fibNum < n);
  return (fibNum==n);
}

function printTable(a){
  var table = "<table><thead><tr><td>Num</td><td>Square</td><td>Fib</td></tr></thead>";
  for(var i=a[0]; i<=a[1]; i++){
    table += "<tr>";
      table += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
      table += "<td>"+(i*i)+"</td>";
      table += "<td>"+((isFib(i))?"yes":"no")+"</td>";
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  return table;
}

document.write( printTable(a) );
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
thead {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Here is an improved `isFib` function that stores the old values so its faster. It still takes about 1 second to calculate all fibs from 1 to 1,000,000 but its way faster than before. If you try to print the table with 1,000,000 records in it to the DOM you will likely crash your browser so dont even bother trying.

```js
var fibs = [1, 2];

function isFib(n) {
  if (fibs[fibs.length - 1] < n) { // not calculated to n yet
    do {
      fibs.push(fibs[fibs.length - 1] + fibs[fibs.length - 2]); // get next fib
    } while (fibs[fibs.length - 1] < n); // do until found to (or above) n
  }
  return (fibs.indexOf(n) > -1); // Is n in the list of fibs?
}
```

Last time i optimized it for speed and got a dramatic speed increase (still not fast enough for your requirements). This attempt optimizes for memory because it only ever stores the last two fibs, but is just as fast, runs in about 1 second.

```js
function printTable(a){
  var previousFib = 1;
  var currentFib = 2;
  function nextFib(){
    var temp = currentFib;
    currentFib += previousFib;
    previousFib = temp;
  }

  var table = "<table><thead><tr><td>Num</td><td>Square</td><td>Fib</td></tr></thead>";
  for(var i=a[0]; i<a[1]; i++){
    table += "<tr>";
      table += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
      table += "<td>"+(i*i)+"</td>";
      table += "<td>";
      if(i==0||i==1) table += "yes";
      else {
        while (currentFib < i){
          nextFib();
          console.log(currentFib);
        }
        table += (currentFib==i)?"yes":"no";
      }
      table += "</td>";
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  return table;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you can do all the formatting yourself to get this to look like your professor requires, but this should give you the correct results.

Comment: I guess I could improve the performance of this by using the previously found fibonacci numbers to calculate the higher valued ones instead of redoing the calculation for each number. If this goes from 1 - 1,000,000 as suggest I'm sure it would take longer than 0.2 seconds. You may need to do some optimization.

Comment: Ok i tried to run this from 1-10,000 and it takes a few minutes. I will attempt to optimize it to run in 0.2 seconds.